# Извлечение полноценной программы из скомпилированного файла

Tags: c#

Предположим, у меня есть проект на C#, который должен работать только от одного скомпилированного .exe файла. 
Возможно ли как-нибудь добавить в него ещё один .exe и несколько директорий с файлами, которые должны "распаковываться" после его запуска? Как?

Comment: Читайте про ресурсы. Хотя, можно и тупо в переменную EXEшник запихать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне когда-то потребовалась подобная задача - собрать все зависимые библиотеки в один exe файл, чтобы внутри exe файла были встроены все мои зависимости. Для этого я воспользовался nuget-пакетов [ILMerge](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ilmerge). 
Эта утилита позволяет объединить несколько сборок(Assembly) в одну сборку(Assembly). Установите в проект nuget-пакет, соберите, и на выходе получите один exe-файл с упакованными внутри зависимостями

Исходный код проекта находиться [здесь](https://github.com/Microsoft/ILMerge)